# How to diff 2 arrays in Javascript and get the minimum number of changes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just started working on a JSON diffing script and came up with a very basic solution.

I first flatten them into an ES6 Map

```
// Flattener
function flatten (obj) {
  const res = new Map()
  _flatten(null, obj, res)
  return res
}

function _flatten (key, obj, res) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    const k = key ? `${key}.` : ''
    const oKeys = Object.keys(obj)

    if (oKeys.length === 0) {
      // Handle empty object
      return res.set(key, Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {})
    }
    else {
      return oKeys.map(x => _flatten(`${k}${x}`, obj[x], res))
    }
  }
  res.set(key, obj)
}
```

Then differ them with a lookup function:

```
function diffing (before, after) {
  const r = new Map([ ['i', []], ['u', []], ['d', []] ])
  const flatBefore = flatten(before)
  const flatAfter = flatten(after)

  flatAfter.forEach((val, key) => {
    const hasKey = flatBefore.has(key)

    if (!hasKey) {
      // Insertion
      const event = { type: 'i', key: key, value: val }
      r.set('i', r.get('i').concat(event))
    }
  })

  flatBefore.forEach((val, key) => {
    const hasKey = flatAfter.has(key)
    const hasChanged = flatAfter.get(key) !== val

    // Update
    if (hasKey) {
      if (hasChanged) {
        const event = { type: 'u', key: key, value: flatAfter.get(key) }
        r.set('u', r.get('u').concat(event))
      }
    }
    else {
      // Deletion
      const event = { type: 'd', key: key, value: val }
      r.set('d', r.get('d').concat(event))
    }
  })

  return r
}
```

This is my first attempt. And I can get any Insertion/Deletion of object keys.

Problems come with array (that are keyed by position). As long as I add or remove an element at the bottom, it works. But if I add an element at the beginning, the whole hashmap breaks.

```
const arr1 = ['google', 'apple', 'facebook', 'amazon', 'microsoft']
const arr2 = ['uber', 'google', 'apple', 'facebook', 'amazon', 'microsoft']

Map {
  '0' => 'google',
  '1' => 'apple',
  '2' => 'facebook',
  '3' => 'amazon',
  '4' => 'microsoft' }
Map {
  '0' => 'uber',
  '1' => 'google',
  '2' => 'apple',
  '3' => 'facebook',
  '4' => 'amazon',
  '5' => 'microsoft' }
Map {
  'i' => [ { type: 'i', key: '5', value: 'microsoft' } ],
  'u' => [ { type: 'u', key: '0', value: 'uber' },
  { type: 'u', key: '1', value: 'google' },
  { type: 'u', key: '2', value: 'apple' },
  { type: 'u', key: '3', value: 'facebook' },
  { type: 'u', key: '4', value: 'amazon' } ],
  'd' => [] }
```

I'm looking for a solution that can be smart enough to actually not reconsider every position but give me the following result:

- Uber has been inserted at position 0

That's it.

I'm not looking for a solution but instead advice on how I can solve this problem and whether I'm on the right path or I'm completely wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should ask for a solution to a specific problem instead of advice on how you can solve the problem. Otherwise, this question qualifies as too broad and will be closed. If you do just want advice, you should check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What if instead of array indices, you keyed them with their identity (e.g. "uber"). As the value you could have it's index.

Comment: have you checked existing JSON-patch diffing libraries?

Comment: you may have a look here: [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)